# map the project with specific tasks name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

[updated]
What i want is have 2 column and the first column display the unique name of the project and the second column display the tasks belong to associated project, any help guys please!!

```
 @foreach (var project in project.GroupBy(project => project.Project) 
      { 


            <tr>
              <td>
                    @project.Key
                     </td>

          </tr>


          }   
      }
    </table>
```

Comment: This overhead the CPU usage, first of all you must store the grouped result in a var. I think is a bad practice use Group inside the expression for a foreach.

Comment: The answer is in your question!

Comment: @AlbertoLeón not really. The GroupBy is only executed once in each `foreach`. Caching the result in a variable would make no difference in performance.

Comment: guys, how do I map the project with the associate task?

Comment: @jrummell Learning new things every day, thanks jrummell

Answer (score 3):

Since you're already in a codeblock with the first @foreach, you can remove the @ sign for the 2nd one..

```
 @foreach (var project in person.GroupBy(project => project.Project, entry => entry)) 
      { 
         foreach (var task in person.GroupBy(task => task.Task, entry => entry))
          {
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the @ sign on the second for each. is not needed since you're already in a Razor block